# Vendor folder is missing in yii2 and composer fails update

Tags: yii2, composer-php

I cloned my project from git. `Vendor` folder is missing in yii2 and when I update composer, it shows

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.9 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.8 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.7 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.6 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.15.1 requires bower-asset/jquery 3.2.*@stable | 3.1.*@stable | 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.15 requires bower-asset/jquery 3.2.*@stable | 3.1.*@stable | 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.14.2 requires bower-asset/jquery 3.2.*@stable | 3.1.*@stable | 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.14.1 requires bower-asset/jquery 3.2.*@stable | 3.1.*@stable | 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.14 requires bower-asset/jquery 3.2.*@stable | 3.1.*@stable | 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.13.3 requires bower-asset/jquery 3.2.*@stable | 3.1.*@stable | 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.13.2 requires bower-asset/jquery 3.2.*@stable | 3.1.*@stable | 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.13.1 requires bower-asset/jquery 3.2.*@stable | 3.1.*@stable | 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.13 requires bower-asset/jquery 3.2.*@stable | 3.1.*@stable | 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.12.2 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.12.1 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.12 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.11.2 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.11.1 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.11 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.10 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 >=2.0.6 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.11.1, 2.0.11.2, 2.0.12, 2.0.12.1, 2.0.12.2, 2.0.13, 2.0.13.1, 2.0.13.2, 2.0.13.3, 2.0.14, 2.0.14.1, 2.0.14.2, 2.0.15, 2.0.15.1, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9].
```

Potential causes:

```
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have your composer updated? Have you executed your requirements executable on your main folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot update yii2 via composer bower-asset/jquery could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25882271/cannot-update-yii2-via-composer-bower-asset-jquery-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 2):

set the aliases in the config:

```
       $config = [
          ...
         'aliases' => [
            '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
            '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
         ],
         ...
      ];
```

and the repositories in the composer.json:

```
    "repositories": [
     {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
     }
    ]
```