# Extension not getting installed through composer in cpanel

Tags: yii2, composer-php, cpanel, yii2-basic-app, yii2-extension

I am using yii2 basic application template. I have VPS server for hosting my software. In my cpanel I have installed composer successfully. Then I uploaded my files from local machine to the server.

Now I want to do composer update in cpanel using Putty.

My composer is as below:

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
    "description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.5",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "nex/yii2-datepicker": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "*",
        "wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "@dev",
    "bupy7/yii2-dynamic-fields": "*",
    "unclead/yii2-multiple-input": "v2.9.0",
    "faryshta/yii2-disable-submit-buttons": "@dev",
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "@dev",
    "mdmsoft/yii2-admin": "*"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "codeception/codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
            "setPermission": [
                {
                    "runtime": "0777",
                    "web/assets": "0777",
                    "yii": "0755"
                }
            ],
            "generateCookieValidationKey": [
                "config/web.php"
            ]
        },
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is fine, when I type the command composer update, it shows the below error

```
[ifsoftware1234@216-10-245-56 basic]$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for nex/yii2-datepicker * -> satisfiable by nex/yii2-datepicker[dev-master].
    - nex/yii2-datepicker dev-master requires bower-asset/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker 4.17.* -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot update yii2 via composer bower-asset/jquery could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25882271/cannot-update-yii2-via-composer-bower-asset-jquery-could-not-be-found)

Comment: You should not run `composer update` on your server - commit your `composer.lock` and use `composer install` to install dependencies from lock.