# how to run existing yii project on windows local

Tags: php, yii2

i have zip of yii project but i don't know how to run it because i never use yii.

i'm trying composer install but it gives me this error
[image]

when i try composer update
[image]

here is my composer.json:

```
{
"name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
"description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
"keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
"homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.28",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget": "*",
    "wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform": "*",
    "gugglegum/yii2-cookie-language-selector": "^1.0",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-field-range": "*",
    "drsdre/yii2-wizardwidget": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-dynagrid": "@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-export": "dev-master",
    "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base": "@dev",
    "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget" : "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-datecontrol": "@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-date-range": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800
},
"scripts": {
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
        "setPermission": [
            {
                "runtime": "0777",
                "web/assets": "0777",
                "yii": "0755"
            }
        ],
        "generateCookieValidationKey": [
            "config/web.php"
        ]
    },
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
}
}
```

but when i try install like usual

composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic

i can run it

Comment: You need to adjust project settings to use asset packagist: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51408266/5812455. Or install asset plugin globally, but it is no longer recommended: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25883991/5812455

Comment: @rob006 I think the fpx asset plugin is not compatible with composer 2.x so the second option won't work unless they downgrade composer.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion i will try it

Comment: Delete composer.lock and test again.

Comment: still error - yiisoft/yii2[2.0.28, ..., 2.0.35] require bower-asset/jquery 3.4.*@stable @hadi aj

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your PHP version on your JSON file and run the command `composer update` that will help you.

After that, if you get the error then check other packages' versions, update the same on the JSON file, and hit the same command which is `composer update`.